# What l kind of progress dialog is this and how do I set it up

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I have seen this progress bar in apps but I don't know what it's called.

[image]
How do I set it up and change it intermediate colors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Swipe-to-Refresh is the one you're referring to.

More info at http://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html

Comment: It's isn't swipe to refresh

Comment: The swipe-to-refreshs I know, have an arrow head at the beginning of the loading. This one doesn't. And more I didn't swip anything when this one appeared

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the color of the spinner and not the background, you can try -

```
            progressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.blue),
            android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Otherwise, to change the background as well, you need to customize your progressbar for this. 
The tutorial [here](https://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com/2011/09/10/customization-of-spinner-progress/) may help you.